# Using .loc with multiple selection criteria

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to run `.loc` to capture a subset of data that requires multiple criteria.  Something like:

```
df.loc[(
    df["date"] > datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2000', '%b %d %Y').date() & 
    df["date"] < datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2009', '%b %d %Y').date() )]
```

Of course, this syntax is incorrect.  What is the correct syntax?

Comment: IIUC you just needed to add parentheses: `df.loc[(
    df["date"] > datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2000', '%b %d %Y').date()) & 
    (df["date"] < datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2009', '%b %d %Y').date() )]` but I also think this would work: `df.loc[(df['date'] > '2000/01/01') & (df['date'] < '2009/01/01')]`

Comment: @EdChum you're right, feel free to submit as answer.

Comment: Did my other suggestion also work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compounding boolean conditions you need to add parentheses due to operator precedence so the following should work:

```
df.loc[( df["date"] > datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2000', '%b %d %Y').date()) & (df["date"] < datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2009', '%b %d %Y').date() )]
```

Also I think it'll be easier just to pass date strings for the comparison:

```
In [6]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2015,2,4))})
df[(df['a'] > '2015/01/14') & (df['a'] < '2015/02/01')]

Out[6]:
            a
14 2015-01-15
15 2015-01-16
16 2015-01-17
17 2015-01-18
18 2015-01-19
19 2015-01-20
20 2015-01-21
21 2015-01-22
22 2015-01-23
23 2015-01-24
24 2015-01-25
25 2015-01-26
26 2015-01-27
27 2015-01-28
28 2015-01-29
29 2015-01-30
30 2015-01-31
```

Comment: Does it stop to check if the first criteria is false? Because in my case, that would save expensive computation of the second criteria.

Comment: @thestruggleisreal yes it should short circuit like all sensible implementations

Comment: But `&` does an union. What if you want an intersection (all criterias have to be true for one row). In the moment it is like  `df.loc[((df['colA']=='nan') | (df['colA'].isnull())& (~(df['colB']!=sth)&(df['colC'].astype(str)).isin(somevalues['colC']))), 'colA'] = 'thisRowFulfilledAtLeastOneCriteria'`

Comment: @thestruggleisreal no `|` is or and is union `&` is intersection and is and